# Is there a way to continue execution rest of the cypress script even if the cypress is stuck on page load?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm writing a Cypress script which should do an automated login, extract cookies and send them to the backend.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that: I'm able to intercept wanted auth request, but rest of my cypress script is not executed due to page load - or at least I'm thinking that is the issue.

```
describe('Fetching auth data', () => {
  it('proccess cookies and send to the API', () => {
    cy.clearCookies();
    cy.visit('https://wanted.login.page');

    cy.intercept({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://my.auth.request'
    }).as('authRequest');

    cy.get('input[id=username]').type(`${Cypress.env('username')}{enter}`);
    cy.get('input[id=password]').type(`${Cypress.env('password')}{enter}`);

    cy.wait('@authRequest').then((inter) => {
        let cookies  
        // do the extraction of cookies and other code...
        // but cypress never enters here
        
        // send cookies to the backend
        cy.request({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/webhooks`,
          json: true,
          headers: {
            'X-App-Token': Cypress.env('webhookToken'),
          },
          body: {
            cookie: formattedCookies,
          },
        });
      });
  });
});
```

As you can see on the picture:

[image: Picture of page load timeout]

It shows that this authRequest is being intercepted but the rest of the code isn't executed.

I'm trying to prevent or stop this page load to be able to execute rest of my code

Comment: Your form refreshes the page you are on. Is this a behaviour you want to do? Might not be needed if you are sending fetch requests, so if you disable that behaviour, it also won't reload the page. And from the screenshot provided, it is not intercepting your request at all, it is waiting for it and it never came.

Comment: If I'm logging thru normal browser, yes it does refresh the page after the login but cypress never does - something is causing this to be stuck. I really don't care if it loads or not, as long as this authRequest is intercepted and data is sent. Also this is what it displays when hovering over authRequest"
This request matched:
cy.intercept() spy with alias @authRequest

Comment: Check in your browser if the request GET is before or after the page reload, you might need to mimick that inside cypress as well.

Comment: it is after the page load. But in the network tab I can see requests continue executing after this page load, only like script is stuck on this step. Do you have any examples on how to do that?